# How to set a background image by code on windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, background

My question is very simple but I don't find a solution that works.

I code a Windows Phone app and I have to change the background. The change depends of the user profile on the application. If the user is a male, the app display a blue background, if she is a female, a pink one.

I've tried to bind the background but I still have a blink effect (black to the background image).
It is very visible when the app navigates between two pages but invisible when the change is made on the same page.

I tried these solutions too but the background stay black:

```csh
string uri = String.Format("/Assets/Background{0}.png", App.Context.SelectedUser.IsMan ? "Boy" : "Girl");
        var imageBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative))
        };
        this.Background = imageBrush;



string uri = String.Format("/Assets/Background{0}.png", App.Context.SelectedUser.IsMan ? "Boy" : "Girl");
        var imageBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative))
        };
        App.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
```

I tried with .jpg and .png image file but none works.

Is my code wrong?
Anyone has a suggestion?

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works in a blank silverlight app in Windows Phone 8.

In Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/boy.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Button Content="Change" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

and in the code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/girl.png", UriKind.Relative);

        var imageBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = bmp
        };

        LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, my code was wrong. A rookie mistake :-/. In my code, I used "this" but it is not the good target. Just like you write, I have to use the Grid ("LayoutRoot" in our case).